# Converting from long to wide, using pivot_wide() on two columns in R

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape2

I would like to transform my data from long format to wide by the values in two columns. How can I do this using `tidyverse`?

**Updated `dput`**

```
structure(list(Country = c("Algeria", "Benin", "Ghana", "Algeria", 
                       "Benin", "Ghana", "Algeria", "Benin", "Ghana"
), Indicator = c("Indicator 1", 
             "Indicator 1", 
             "Indicator 1", 
             "Indicator 2", 
             "Indicator 2", 
             "Indicator 2",
             "Indicator 3", 
             "Indicator 3", 
             "Indicator 3"
), Status = c("Actual", "Forecast", "Target", "Actual", "Forecast", 
          "Target", "Actual", "Forecast", "Target"), Value = c(34, 15, 5, 
                                                               28, 5, 2, 43, 5, 
                                                               1)), row.names 
= c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


    Country Indicator   Status   Value
    <chr>   <chr>       <chr>    <dbl>
1 Algeria Indicator 1 Actual      34
2 Benin   Indicator 1 Forecast    15
3 Ghana   Indicator 1 Target       5
4 Algeria Indicator 2 Actual      28
5 Benin   Indicator 2 Forecast     5
6 Ghana   Indicator 2 Target       2
7 Algeria Indicator 3 Actual      43
8 Benin   Indicator 3 Forecast     5
9 Ghana   Indicator 3 Target       1
```

Expected output

```
Country Indicator1_Actual Indicator1_Forecast Indicator1_Target Indicator2_Actual

Algeria       34                    15                 5           28
```

etc

Appreciate any tips!

```
foo <- data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = c("Indicator","Status"), values_from = "Value")
```

**works perfectly!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mistake is in your `pivot_wider()` command
`data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Indicator, values_from = c(Indicator, Status))`

I bet you can't use the same column for both names and values.

Try this code

```
data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = c(Indicator, Status), values_from = Value))
```

Explanation:  Since you want the **column names** to be *Indicator 1_Actual*, you need both columns indicator and status going into your `names_from`

It would be helpful if you provided example data and expected output. But I tested this on my dummy data and it gives the expected output -

Data:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     a1    a2 a3       a4
  <int> <int> <chr> <dbl>
1     1     5 s        10
2     2     4 s        20
3     3     3 n        30
4     4     2 n        40
```

Call : `a %>% pivot_wider(names_from = c(a2, a3), values_from = a4)`

Output :

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     a1 `5_s` `4_s` `3_n` `2_n`
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10    NA    NA    NA
2     2    NA    20    NA    NA
3     3    NA    NA    30    NA
4     4    NA    NA    NA    40
```

Data here if you want to reproduce

```
structure(list(a1 = 1:4, a2 = 5:2, a3 = c("s", "s", "n", "n"), 
    a4 = c(10, 20, 30, 40)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Edit : For the edited question after trying out the correct `pivot_wider()` command - It looks like your data could actually have duplicates, in which case the output you are seeing would make sense - I would suggest you try to figure out if your data actually has duplicates by using `filter(Country == .., Indicator == .., Status == ..)`

Comment: I updated the question, I made a mistake, added value column

Comment: Thanks @AnakinSkywalker the `Value` column enabled me to figure out what you were trying to do. Could you post your actual data with `dput(.your data frame)` or a reduced version of your data with head(data frame) so I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: It looks like you are excluding a few columns in your pivot_wider call hence the new columns don't have unique values for each Country. So making lists with `c(.,.,.)` is expected. Make sure you are passing all your data into pivot_wider() and don't pass only region into the `id_cols` parameter

Comment: I created a normal example for you

Comment: Hmm. I can't figure out anything wrong with the subset of the data you have posted. I would say try to figure out if your data actually has duplicates by using `filter(Country == .., Indicator == .., Status == ..)`

Comment: I found some duplicates! Thanks for your time! Need to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by calling both your columns to pivot wider in the `names_from` argument in `pivot_wider()`.

```
data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("Indicator","Status"),
              values_from = "Value")
```

Result

```
  Country `Indicator 1_Ac… `Indicator 1_Fo… `Indicator 1_Ta… `Indicator 2_Ac… `Indicator 2_Fo…
  <chr>              <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1 Algeria               34               15                5               28                5
```

Comment: Possibly because you have more than one country?

Comment: Yes, I have more than one country

Comment: Actually, this should still work without multiple countries. Do you have an error message pop up? I've edited my answer to show the result

Comment: I do not know. I updated for 3 countries for you and printed the output.

Comment: Could be several things. Firstly, the columns names aren't the friendliest to use in R. Try to stick to '_' to instead of a space. Your actual data must be different to the example you've given.

Comment: I printed first 9 rows from the original dataframe

Comment: What happens when you add `id_cols = "Country"`?. So `data %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = "Country", names_from = c("Indicator","Status"),values_from = "Value")`

Comment: Nothing changes. Something is wrong with data probably. It shows me there are some duplicates.

Comment: Are the first 9 rows different to the actual dataset? The print screen you provided suggests otherwise. Maybe replace the print screen with a print screen of the actual data. That may help

Comment: you are right, on dput it works as expected. Something is wrong with my data

Comment: Thanks for your time! I accepted another answer because he was the first chronologically. But I greatly appreciate your time!